# Publishing Code to Function App using Azure Powershell is failing with error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I have an Azure Function App and I am trying to publish the C# code which is a zip file to the newly created function app using the Azure Powershell Command.

Here is the command I am using

```
Publish-AzWebapp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $FunctionAppName -ArchivePath $ArchivePath -Force
```

And I am getting the below error

```
Publish-AzWebapp : One or more errors occurred.
```

I tried using Verbose and Debug flags and I am still unable to get any more info other than the above.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After creating function app in Azure, you need to add one of the applications setting when deploying the zip package of Function App i.e., `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` to `true` in the Configuration > Application Settings.

Then you start publishing your zip package of function project to the Azure Function App using the given PowerShell command:

```
Publish-AzWebapp -ResourceGroupName rg-rajoli -Name KrishFuncAppRepro35 -ArchivePath C:\Users\rajoli\source\repos\KrishNet6Funchttp02.zip
```

**Result**:

[image]

My Azure Functions Project Zip Package contains One Http Trigger:

[image]

**In Azure Portal Function App**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks will try this! One question, If we didn't enable that setting, will it fail with the same error as it is failing for mine?

Comment: Not Failing exactly, but functions will be empty until we do that setting to true as specified in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#deployment-customization)